# How to display the function doc in the vscode python interactive window?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get the doc of functions in the interactive window similar to when typing `len?` 
in IPython which displays the function `len()` manual.

However when I do this in the VScode python interactive window nothing happens.

The cell seems to be running but nothing is displayed and eventually returns to the prompt.

Is there anyway to get the function hel similar to what IPython does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature hasn't been implemented yet. It's actually in progress.

See this item in our issues list:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4170